# how to specify text on BarGraphItem pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, pyside6

i need to set up text to bar using BarGraphItem with pyqtgraph

I need something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOMlM.png)
or set the names in the middle.

there was an idea to set TextItem by coordinates,
but after writing it, it turned out that with a large number of such elements, they begin to slow down.

Comment: this looks relatively simple.  what have you tried so far or where are you stuck ?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)